# spring 4.3.7 and weblogic 12.2.1 Rest integration has error

Tags: java, spring, rest, weblogic12c

i have an restful spring web app that i want to deploy in weblogic.deploying this in tomcat works fine but in weblogic i got this error:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson /databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter;
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:278)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

i have tried different jackson lib versions:2.6 2.7 2.7.6 2.8 2.8.7 2.8.8 and 2.9 but it has same error.
my controller class:
    package com.rest.springmvc.controller;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import com.rest.springmvc.model.User;
import com.rest.springmvc.service.UserService;

@RestController
public class RestController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;  //Service which will do all data retrieval/manipulation work


//-------------------Retrieve All Users--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
//-------------------Retrieve Single User--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
}



//-------------------Create a User--------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user,  UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());

    if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
        System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

    userService.saveUser(user);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getId()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}


//------------------- Update a User --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
    System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

    User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

    if (currentUser==null) {
        System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    currentUser.setName(user.getName());
    currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
    currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());

    userService.updateUser(currentUser);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
}

//------------------- Delete a User --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);

    User user = userService.findById(id);
    if (user == null) {
        System.out.println("Unable to delete. User with id " + id + " not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    userService.deleteUserById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}


//------------------- Delete All User --------------------------------------------------------

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<User> deleteAllUsers() {
    System.out.println("Deleting All Users");

    userService.deleteAllUsers();
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

}

application successfully deploys but when i post http://localhost:7001/user/ i got that error in weblogic.

Comment: it seems to be a classloader issues. Did you try to isolate your webapp classloader? did you try to configure the classoloader by specifyin gthat you want to use your webapp classloader first and then the parent classloader?

Comment: no.how i must do this?im new to weblogic.

Comment: oh that worked.ive searched whole web and this was many peoples problem.write it so i mark this as answer.i used this in my weblogic.xml and it worked.
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the weblogic.xml file to your application. In this file, add the tag `prefer-application-packages` whith package `com.fasterxml.jackson`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

     <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.1</wls:weblogic-version>
     <wls:context-root>FilterWeb</wls:context-root>
     <wls:container-descriptor>
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
             <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson</wls:package-name>
         </wls:prefer-application-packages>
     </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates that *the class no longer has a definition of that method*. This could be due to library version invoked by Weblogic being different from your application's intended version.

**Finding the jar** :

1. Temporarily add a `-verbose:class` argument to the server's JVM
   arguments.
2. In server's out file, you will be able to see the *.jar
   that is being loaded.

If the jar version is different from the version you expected, you could consider upgrading your application to newer version of the library. If that's not possible, a small workaround by using this [parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP660).

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be a classloader issues. 
Try to isolate your webapp classloader by configuring it in order you want to use your webapp classloader first and then the parent classloader